# Unable to use Android Device Manager to reset my Password

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, password, locked-out, android-device-manager

I recently locked my Nexus 7 (2013) having Android 5.0.2 with a password, which I forgot. I, then, thought to use Device Manager, since I've authorized it from Google Settings to make changes, such as locating and changing password.

Previously, my PIN used to get reset from ADM, but, this this time I am using a Password. Is that the reason?

This is what it says, "We successfully sent a lock request to your device."

And after that when I rejoice and feel a bit relieved, "Since Google has verified that a screen lock is already set, the password that you entered won't be needed."

I am trying to override my previous password over this new password..

Screenshot is also attached!
[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1vab.png)

Is there any other way of resetting the password except ADM, on Android 5.0.2, like that Google Account's credentials it used to ask on Froyo.

P.S. I've set all permissions for ADM at Google Settings on my Nexus.

Comment: Have you tried entering the wrong password until the "Forgot password?" button shows up, and resetting your password from here using your Google account?